# Its posible to use Self-Update in a RCP aplicaction that is based on plugins?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

That's the question.
I have an application that start as based on plugins ( starts in pde version 3.1 )
now I'm upgrading that application.

The main issue is that I don't fully understand the whole procedure, the whole picture.
I followed Vogella Tutorials, wiki in eclipse, but nothing is equal of what I have.

Also if I change my "product" configuration from plug-ins to features, the export process didn't work, and show me an error.

As far I can see, when you want this scenario, you have to create a "RCP Plugin Project" and a "Feature Project", where each one depends on the other.
"RCP Plugin project" should be feature based.

And then the "Feature Project" create a "Update Site Project".
But when "RCP Plugin project" is based on "plug-ins" all the cicle breaks, and I can't add a dependency to "feature Project" .

Is there any way to use this "Self Update scenario" with plugin based product?
Or I can convert to P2 ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is possible to provide update functionality in RCP applications. Today the simplest way is to use p2 for this.

For this reason you will be needing an update site, and a p2-enabled RCP product.

About features, plug-ins and dependencies: a feature is basically a container for plug-ins; plug-ins basically contribute the code to execute. A feature contains plug-ins, and automatically depends on all the plug-ins that the contained plug-ins depend on, so there is no need to add the contained projects as dependencies to the feature. On the other hand, the plug-in project should and must not know about the features that contain them - that would introduce dependency cycles that are impossible to manage.

About update site projects: don't use them - they are a legacy project type used by the old Update manager - for p2 it is better to simply export features. For details I shamelessly offer my [own blog post](http://cubussapiens.hu/2010/08/update-sites-in-the-p2-era/) from last year.

Then you can add the required p2 elements to your application - basically you have to make sure that the p2 plug-ins are present and executed during runtime. You can either reuse the p2 update GUI from the IDE, or you can roll your own. Details about this functionality is found in the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application) and in [Andrew Niefers](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/03/building-p2-rcp-products-in-eclipse.html) blog post (also linked from the wiki page).

**Update**: and a [brand new corresponding post](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/10/20/eclipse-rcp-updates-with-p2-got-sooo-much-easier/) on vogella.de

Comment: Thanks Zoltán, I'll read your blog. But now I wonder where to put the url from where the app should check for updates.

Comment: For that see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application#Updating_from_the_Cloud in the wiki page. That part lists an example project and some other details needed.

Comment: Thanks Again Zoltán but I have no lucky. I have Eclipse 3.7.1, and every package that I import, i receive a warnig "Discourage". My goal is to have my app pointing only to my web site url, and there I'll have a future deployed project, where teh app should search download and install updated, automatically. Any idea ? what i'm doing wrong ? (besides try to undestand this in two days)

Comment: Now I have my app with P2 enabled. 1) how to remove old update schema ? 2) even I created a p2.inf file, I can't see availables sites for download updates... any suggestion. Sorry for the time consuming of this questions

Comment: I don't think that p2 offers automatic update checking by default. It provides an update mechanism, but does not say when will it be triggered. If you want to update automatically, you have to write some code to trigger that mechanism; but for that I cannot help you any more (I've never programmed using the p2 API).

Comment: Addition: Lars Vogel updated his corresponding tutorial. I added a link to it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Zoltán, I'll try to follow Lars tutorial, but my main problem is that my app is "plugin-based" and not "feature based" ...